# Thinkpad fn key - ubuntu 18.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, thinkpad

I have a thinkpad x250 which, for almost everything, worked flawlessly out of the box with ubuntu 18.04.

But <kbd>fn</kbd> key doesn't seem to behave, pressing it alone changes the keyboard backlight, it doesn't work in combination (<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> for example), some work if <kbd>fn</kbd> is locked with <kbd>ESC</kbd>, and some others don't. acpi_listen recognize most of them, but gnome seems to ignore some that acpi recognize.

What I've researched seems to be either outdated, fragmentary, or both. What I need, more than a concrete solution, which will be nice, is a guiding light of how this actually works under ubuntu to fix the behavior.

EDIT: looking at showkey or evtest output, apparently pressing <kbd>fn</kbd> alone produces a few key events, (as KEY_WAKEUP) including <kbd>space</kbd>, which makes sense with keyboard backlight activation.

Using BIOS swap <kbd>fn</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd> option make hotkeys work, but <kbd>fn</kbd> (now KEY_LEFTCTRL) still seems to add a few events apart of expected, at its own will, apparently in a too intelligent way to be keyboard malfunction. Still lost at this one.

---

installing HWE made things more bearable. Upgrading to 20.4 sorted it.